# "col" argument in plot function not working when a factor value is used for x - axis

Tags: r, plot

I am doing quarterly analysis, for which I want to plot a graph. To maintain continuity on x axis I have turned quarters into factors. But then when I am using plot function and trying to color it red, the `col` argument is not working.

An example:

```
quarterly_analysis <- data.frame(Quarter = as.factor(c(2020.1,2020.2,2020.3,2020.4,2021.1,2021.2,2021.3,2021.4)),
  AvgDefault = as.numeric(c(0.24,0.27,0.17,0.35,0.32,0.42,0.38,0.40)))


plot(quarterly_analysis, col="red")
```

But I am getting the graph in black color as shown below:

[image: 1]

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Converting it to a factor is not ideal to plot unless you have multiple values for each factor - it tries to plot a box plot-style plot. For example, with 10 observations in the same factor, the `col = "red"` color shows up as the fill:

```
set.seed(123)
fact_example <- data.frame(factvar = as.factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], 10)),
                           numvar = runif(30))

plot(fact_example$factvar, fact_example$numvar,
     col = "red")
```

[image]

With only one observation for each factor, this is not ideal because it is just showing you the line that the box plot would make.

You could use `border = "red`:

```
plot(quarterly_analysis$Quarter, 
     quarterly_analysis$AvgDefault, border="red")
```

[image]

Or if you want more flexibility, you can plot it numerically and do a little tweaking for more control (i.e., can change the `pch`, or make it a line graph):

```
# make numeric x values to plot
x_vals <- as.numeric(substr(quarterly_analysis$Quarter,1,4)) + rep(seq(0, 1, length.out = 4))

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(x_vals, 
     quarterly_analysis$AvgDefault, col="red",
     pch = 7, main = "Square Symbol", axes = FALSE)
  axis(1, at = x_vals,
     labels = quarterly_analysis$Quarter)
  axis(2)

plot(x_vals, 
     quarterly_analysis$AvgDefault, col="red",
     type = "l", main = "Line graph", axes = FALSE)
  axis(1, at = x_vals,
     labels = quarterly_analysis$Quarter)
  axis(2)

plot(x_vals, 
     quarterly_analysis$AvgDefault, col="red",
     type = "b", pch = 7, main = "Both", axes = FALSE)
  axis(1, at = x_vals,
     labels = quarterly_analysis$Quarter)
  axis(2)
```

[image]

Data

```
set.seed(123)
quarterly_analysis <- data.frame(Quarter = as.factor(paste0(2019:2022,
                                                            rep(c(".1", ".2", ".3", ".4"), 
                                                                each = 4))),
                                 AvgDefault = runif(16))
quarterly_analysis <- quarterly_analysis[order(quarterly_analysis$Quarter),]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But on x - axis I wanted continuity i.e. after 2019.4, 2020.1 should come directly and not 2019.5, that is why I converted them into factors. Is there any other way to solve this issue ?

Comment: What you described is how it is on the figure, it's just not printing all of the labels on the x axis due to space limitations  - its skipping every other quarter. If you look, there is a tick mark between "2019.3" and "2020.1" which reflect "2019.4" - if you widen the figure in the viewer or on export it will print all the values in the order you described.

Comment: @Priyansh - the above comments were for when plotting as a factor - see edits for a workaround when taking the more flexible option of plotting without converting to a factor